# Cannot deserialize old Avro data after adding array field

Tags: java, avro

I had an AVDL file that contains single record in it. I used it for message passing in Kafka. After adding an array I got exception. I already added some extra fields at the end of record but no exception occurred.

last field:

```
union {array<string>,null} arrayFieldName={"doc":"array field description"};
```

Deserializer:

```
 Schema messageSchema=Class<T extends SpecificRecordBase> messageType.newInstance().getSchema();
 DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader =  new SpecificDatumReader<>(messageSchema);
 Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, null);
 GenericRecord  result = datumReader.read(null, decoder);`
```

exception:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem? I really need this array field.